# How do I maximize a gnome-terminal that has been minimized?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal

How do I maximize a gnome-terminal window that has been minimized?  I don't see them in the Launcher on the left nor the task bar on the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it with

`unity --reset`

Unfortunately, you need to open a new terminal to do this. The command also seems to hang, in that it doesn't return to the command prompt. However, the original terminal does get maximized so this is a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

See the little dots the 2 arrows I included point to?

[image]

Click there.

You can also do alt-tab to line up all open items and then choose the one that shows gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle through the open programs and windows by using the key combination Alt Tab.

As Rinzwind shows in the screen capture, the arrows show you the open windows. Ubuntu does sometime group them when you are cycling through the open applications with Alt Tab. All you have to do then is to wait over the program that interest you without releasing the Tab key and all available windows will be made available for you to choose. Use the arrow keys then to select the want you want to see.